# "The metashape software" or just "metashape software"

Tags: articles, nouns

I have to write this sentence about <strike>a</strike> software called here "Metashape ":

> "Images were processed with the algorithm implemented in ... **Metashape software**"

Should i write "the Metashape software" or just "metashape software"?

The alternative is "the Metashape " or "Metashape "?

why?

Comment: We need a clearer example.  Is "xyz" a proper name, like "Adobe Photoshop", or a general term, like "GIS mapping"?

Comment: @stangdon ok, i thought was better to make it general. I changed it.
 the name of the software is "metashape" so i'm talking about a specific software not a general term, but i have to write a similar sentence for "Qgis" as well, in any case I'm talking about specific software. Basically i would like to understand the grammar rule

Comment: You should worry more about the *totally* unwanted / non-idiomatic indefinite article ***a** software*, not the (largely stylistic) choice between using or not using a definite article with ***metashape software*** (where most native speakers probably wouldn't notice or care which choice you made).

Comment: Note that "Metashape" has a capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think neither construction is quite right (though both would be understood). Using "software" is ungainly.

I would write

> Images were **processed** using GIMP (or ImageMagick, or Photoshop, or Mathematica).

If you want to call attention to a particular algorithm, rewrite accordingly:

> Images were **sharpened** using GIMP (or ImageMagick, or Photoshop, or Mathematica).